# remove punctuation and stop words from all ".txt" and ".docx " files in a zip folder

Tags: python-3.x, string, nltk, glob, file-handling

Actually I have Eight ".txt" files and two ".docx" files in file_list. My task is to eliminate all stop words and punctuations from all files in file list.I just provided some part of code where I am facing error. can someone please guide me how to eliminate stop words and punctuations from my all file types. I tried the following code but am unable to execute it succesfully. I am also providing folder here.[file_list](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AmLRwD-5wlg6GK2R3i-JvmdPuzkYPKmD/view?usp=sharing). Also when I am running the following code I am facing UTF-8 error for .docx files.

```
from string import punctuation

for each_file in range(1, len(file_list)):
    print("Current working filename is:",file_list[each_file],end="\n") 
    with open(file_list[each_file],'r',encoding='utf-8') as file:
        without_punct = [char for char in file.readlines() if char not in punctuation]
    print(without_punct)
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'stop words'?

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the encoding error for the .docx files because a .docx file is not a standard text file, meaning that it has its own format. Python natively supports reading plain text files, which is why this works for .txt files, but not .docx files. I suggest using a library such as [python-docx](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to extract the text from the .docx files